# How to use several hot strings with special characters at one place?

Tags: autohotkey

To expand **`l2r`** to **`$L^2(\Bbb{R})$`** I use

```
:*:l2r::$L^2(\Bbb{R})$
```

However it always expands to

```
$L(\BbbR)$
```

I don't understand. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean by "compact similar strings at once" you can try something like this:

```
:*:st1::    ; Send text1
text =
(
text1_line1
text1_line2
)
SendText(text)
return

:*:st2::    ; Send text2
text =
(
text2_line1
text2_line2
text2_line3
)
SendText(text)
return

SendText(text){
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; save clipboard
    clipboard := ""                 ; empty clipboard 
    clipboard =  %text%             ; send this text to the clipboard:
    ClipWait, 1                     ; wait for the clipboard to contain data
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 300
    clipboard := ClipSaved          ; restore original clipboard
}
```

OR

Put all your texts in a second script (My texts.ahk) in the same directory as your main script and include it in the auto-execute section of the main script:

My texts.ahk:

```
text1 =
(
text1_line1
text1_line2
)

text2 =
(
text2_line1
text2_line2
text2_line3
)
```

main script.ahk:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
; ...
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\My texts.ahk
; ...
            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

:*:st1::    ; Send text1
    SendText(text1)
return

:*:st2::    ; Send text2
    SendText(text2)
return


SendText(text){
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; save clipboard
    clipboard := ""                 ; empty clipboard 
    clipboard =  %text%             ; send this text to the clipboard:
    ClipWait, 1                     ; wait for the clipboard to contain data
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 300
    clipboard := ClipSaved          ; restore original clipboard
}
```

Comment: Can I put the `SendText` module in `mytext.ahk` script then just `#Include` it in the main one?

Comment: It isn't the best practice to add a function definition to the auto-execute section, unless it's necessary for the start or the performance of the script. Personally, I prefer to put my funtions in a  [local library](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#lib), so that other scripts in the same directory can make use of them.

Answer (score 1):

Comma, semicolon, and other characters such as {}^!+# have special meaning in AHK and need to be escaped in order to be interpreted differently than it normally would. See [EscapeChar](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm).

```
:*:l2r::$L{^}2(\Bbb{{}R{}})$
```

The easiest and fastest way to send such a text or a long text is this:

```
:*:l2r::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll      ; save clipboard
clipboard := ""                ; empty clipboard
clipboard =                    ; send this text to the clipboard:
(
$L^2(\Bbb{R})$
)
ClipWait, 1                    ; wait for the clipboard to contain data
Send, ^v
Sleep, 300
clipboard := ClipSaved         ; restore original clipboard
return
```

Try also:

```
:*:l2r::
SendRaw,
(
$L^2(\Bbb{R})$
)
return
```

Comment: what is the advantages of using the first method? Why is it faster than just `SendRaw`?

Comment: SendRaw may not work in some programs. The clipboard method is much faster (almost instantly), especially if you have to send a long text.

Comment: How to compact similar strings at once, so that I only need to use `SendRaw` or `ClipSaved` in one place?

Comment: See my next answer.